# HTML code inside controls: ComboBox, TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, native

I'm looking for a way to display full HTML in the components (like ComboBox - Select, TextArea) on a web page. Is it somehow possible to do with the native HTML controls, ex. extending them? Are there any extensions that would be useful for me?

Thanks,
Rafal

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how CKEditor renders it's view on the client - it's effectively an Rich Text Editor for browsers (there's lots of other alternatives, too):

http://ckeditor.com/demo
http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/index.html

Looking at the construction of these with the IE Developer Toolbar, Firebug etc is a real learning experience.

An approach many people take is to embed their text area in a div, and also have a another div that's hidden. Underneath, are tabs, for example, Editor, Preview. Clicking on preview takes the HTML in the text box and does something like previewDiv.innerHTML = textbox.value;

I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you want, but an example of this is here:

http://www.freetextbox.com/demos/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you dash for these examples. Do you know any library that would ex. make me able to create combobox with <sub>, <sup> or <img> inside the options? Maybe a GWT extension?

Comment: CKEditor does - the icon that looks like x-squared is superscript, the x2-subscript is subscript and the picture box icon lets you insert an image.